# Dataflow job failed after more than 6 hours with "The worker lost contact with the service"?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, spacy

I am using `Dataflow` to read data from `BigQuery` and then do NLP preprocessing using python. I am using `Python 3` and `SDK 2.16.0`. I am using 100 workers (provite IP, private access and Cloud NAT) with workers in `europe-west6` and endpoint in `europe-west1`. The `BigQuery` tables are in `US`. Test jobs were working without any issue  but when trying to process the full table (32 GB), the job failed after 6h 40 min and it is hard to fully understand what is the underlying error.

First the following is reported by Dataflow:
[image]
It is a bit confusing:  in one case work item failed, 2 other workers lost contact with the service and one workers has been reported dead!

Now let see the logs of reading BigQuery data:
[image]
The first thing that is suspicious is this message "Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)" that appear every 3 second during the full dataflow job. I don't think this is related to the crash but this is strange. The timestamp of the issue with BigQuery (16:28:07 and 16:28:15) appear after the issue reported with the workers (16:27:44).

```
An exception was raised when trying to execute the workitem 7962803802081012962 : Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 176, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 48, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/nativefileio.py", line 204, in __iter__
    for record in self.read_next_block():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/nativeavroio.py", line 198, in read_next_block
    fastavro_block = next(self._block_iterator)
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 738, in fastavro._read.file_reader.next
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 662, in _iter_avro_blocks
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 595, in fastavro._read.null_read_block
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 597, in fastavro._read.null_read_block
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 304, in fastavro._read.read_bytes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 113, in readinto
    data = self._downloader.get_range(start, end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 522, in get_range
    self._downloader.GetRange(start, end - 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 486, in GetRange
    response = self.__ProcessResponse(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 424, in __ProcessResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(response)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/xxx/o/beam%2Ftemp%2Fstackoverflow-raphael-191119-084402.1574153042.687677%2F11710707918635668555%2F000000000009.avro?alt=media&generation=1574154204169350>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UpgIuanY0AawrT7fRC_VW3aRfWSdrrTwT_TqQx1fPAAAUohVoL-8Z8Zw_aYUQcSMNqKIh5R2TulvgHHsoxLWo2gl6wUEA', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 19 Nov 2019 15:28:07 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'expires': 'Tue, 19 Nov 2019 15:28:07 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'content-length': '142', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': '404'}>, content <No such object: nlp-text-classification/beam/temp/stackoverflow-xxxx-191119-084402.1574153042.687677/11710707918635668555/000000000009.avro>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/batchworker.py", line 649, in do_work
    work_executor.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/executor.py", line 176, in execute
    op.start()
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 38, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 39, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 44, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "dataflow_worker/native_operations.py", line 48, in dataflow_worker.native_operations.NativeReadOperation.start
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/nativefileio.py", line 204, in __iter__
    for record in self.read_next_block():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dataflow_worker/nativeavroio.py", line 198, in read_next_block
    fastavro_block = next(self._block_iterator)
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 738, in fastavro._read.file_reader.next
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 662, in _iter_avro_blocks
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 595, in fastavro._read.null_read_block
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 597, in fastavro._read.null_read_block
  File "fastavro/_read.pyx", line 304, in fastavro._read.read_bytes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/filesystemio.py", line 113, in readinto
    data = self._downloader.get_range(start, end)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/gcsio.py", line 522, in get_range
    self._downloader.GetRange(start, end - 1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 486, in GetRange
    response = self.__ProcessResponse(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apitools/base/py/transfer.py", line 424, in __ProcessResponse
    raise exceptions.HttpError.FromResponse(response)
apitools.base.py.exceptions.HttpNotFoundError: HttpError accessing <https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/xxxx/o/beam%2Ftemp%2Fstackoverflow-raphael-191119-084402.1574153042.687677%2F11710707918635668555%2F000000000009.avro?alt=media&generation=1574154204169350>: response: <{'x-guploader-uploadid': 'AEnB2UpgIuanY0AawrT7fRC_VW3aRfWSdrrTwT_TqQx1fPAAAUohVoL-8Z8Zw_aYUQcSMNqKIh5R2TulvgHHsoxLWo2gl6wUEA', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8', 'date': 'Tue, 19 Nov 2019 15:28:07 GMT', 'vary': 'Origin, X-Origin', 'expires': 'Tue, 19 Nov 2019 15:28:07 GMT', 'cache-control': 'private, max-age=0', 'content-length': '142', 'server': 'UploadServer', 'status': '404'}>, content <No such object: nlp-text-classification/beam/temp/stackoverflow-xxxx-191119-084402.1574153042.687677/11710707918635668555/000000000009.avro>
timestamp   
2019-11-19T15:28:07.770312309Z
logger  
root:batchworker.py:do_work
severity    
ERROR
worker  
stackoverflow-xxxx-191-11190044-7wyy-harness-2k89
step    
Read Posts from BigQuery
thread  
73:140029564072960
```

It seems the workers cannot find some avro files on Cloud Storage. This could be related to the message "The workers lost contact with the service"

If I look at "ERROR" I see a lot of them so it seems that the workers itsefl were having issues:
[image]

Looking at `Stack Traces` doesn't give more more hints.

My questions are the following:

1. how we can be sure that the issue is related to the workers ?
2. what can be the reason ? memory ? disk ? or transient issue ?
3. is there an option to recover in case workers are dead ? why the full job is stopping is 3/98 workers are dead or get lost ? Is there a parameter for that ?

Our setup:

- 50  GB disk per VM (I think the rest ate the default parameters)
- DISKS_TOTAL_GB: 6144
- Other quotas related to CPU to have 100 workers. All the rest are the default private user parameters

[image]

We were monitoring with Stackdriver some quantities but to me nothing look wrong:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some test and after few plots for monitoring, it was clear that even if the length of the text was the sime the processing time started to augment rapidly (botton right plot)
[image]

Then it became clear that the issue was with SpaCy 2.1.8 (memory leak).

[image]

Using Spacy 2.2.3 fix the issue. Now the 32 Gb of data are processed in 4h30 without any issue.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The default for Batch jobs not using Dataflow Shuffle is 250GB, so your setting of 50GB is leaving very little space for any shuffle data that needs to be stored on the worker.

It would be good to see the shape of your pipeline (what are the steps involved), but based on the log screenshots, you have 4 steps (read from BQ, preprocess, write to BQ, also write to GCS). I also see some GroupBy operations. The GroupBy operations will requite shuffling, and your 50GB disks might be limiting storage.

You should try a couple of things:
- don't limit the Workers to 50GB (remove the diskGB setting so that Dataflow can use defaults)
- try Dataflow Shuffle (--experiments=shuffle_mode=service)
see https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-shuffle

When you use Dataflow Shuffle, the diskGB parameter has a 30GB default. You can use small disks then (I would still recommend not setting diskGBSize yourself)

Comment: Thanks, yes I will try with 250 GB per VM. I cannot try Dataflow Shuffle since I got all my quotas of 25 TB of disks in europe-west6 where it is not yet available (if I got it right). The heavy python processing is done in the second steps where NLP preproceesing is done on the text which can very sort or very long. I think it explain why I am getting "Processing lull for over 600 seconds in state processs-msecs ub step s2". Is there a way tune this parameters ? or this is not a good sign. I got a lot of these messages during the full 6 hours processing

Comment: Is there a way wherein you can copy the data from US to Europe for your bigquery table? Depending on the size of the data this can be a slow process as lot of data will go over the network. I would suggest that as part of your process export the table from BQ to GCS bucket in US --> Copy from GCS US to Europe --> Upload data into BQ Europe and then run the job. We can isolate the problem to see if it is a network issue or a dataflow issue.

Comment: Using the default 250 GB per VM didn't solve the issue. There is something wrong somewhere and I don't believe at this stage that this is related to the network. It seems that Dataflow start to process 8M entries. Then after 2 hours from the 8M it go downs to 4 millions so half of the job didn't succed or were killed. Nothing in the logs. There is only a lot of message of  "Processing lull for over xxx seconds in state process-msecs in step s2" that appear in the same time. Making more monitoring plots to understand the issue. SpaCy can be very very slow and may be the issue

Comment: The issue was a memory leak with Spacy. I will post more details later.